# Python - C program for loop equivalent

Tags: python, c

I was using the following `for` loop in my C program:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
    //some operation using the index values
  }
}
```

What would be the python equivalent for the second `for` loop, (`j = i + 1`)? I tried the following but there is an error:

```
for indexi, i in enumerate(list):
    for indexj = indexi + 1, j in enumerate(list):
```

How to do it?

Comment: Side-note: Don't name your variable `list` (or any other built-in name). That's just asking for trouble. My answer used `mylist` as a safe placeholder.

Comment: another side-note: rather than stating that "there is an error" it can often be quite helpful to *post* that error.

Comment: Overwriting the name of a standard-type makes it unreachable for other calls. **Do not!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to get the actual index values for some reason (and/or need to control the inner loop separate from the outer), you'd do:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(mylist)):

# Or for indices and elements:
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    for j, y in enumerate(mylist[i+1:], start=i+1):
```

But if what you really want is unique non-repeating pairings of the elements, there is a better way, [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

for x, y in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
```

That gets the values, not the indices, but usually, that what you really wanted. If you really need indices too, you can mix with `enumerate`:

```
for (i, x), (j, y) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(mylist), 2):
```

Which gets the exact index pattern you're looking for, as well as the values. You can also use it to efficiently produce the indices alone as a single loop with:

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(mylist)), 2):
```

Short answer: `itertools` is magical for stuff like this.

Comment: FYI, I followed the convention of `i` and `j` referring to indices, while `x` and `y` refer to values. Your original question uses `i` and `j` for the values, which will trip up maintainers. Obviously, meaningful names are best (and `i` and `j` might be better made `ix` and `iy` to indicate the index relationship with `x` and `y`), but for example code, I'll stick with conventional one-letter names.

Answer (score 3):

If you're really just interested in the indexes, you can use `range` rather than `enumerate`.

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i+1, 5):
        print i, j
```